# A script that print's lines of a file with their length

Tags: shell-script

I’m working on a task that I’m asked to create a script which gets a file name as a parameter and then it’s suppose to print all the lines in the file plus their length in the end of them 
for instance:
banana milk =>banana milk 11
unix and linux =>unix and linux 14
macbook pro =>macbook pro  11

Comment: So what is your question? what have you tried? what part of the task are you having difficulty with, exactly?

Comment: I want to declare a while loop that keeps this code running till the number of the lines in the file  #!/bin/bash
cat $1
cat $1 | wc -m

Comment: It doesn't matter how many lines the file has, wc will count each byte and give you the total at the end. Or you mean you have a directory with a lot of files and you need to process this one command for everyone file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` solution is the best one,
but, if you don’t want to use awk, here are some alternatives:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
        printf "%s %d\n" "$line" "${#line}"
done < "$1"
```

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
        printf "%s %d\n" "$line" "$(expr "$line" : '.*')"
done < "$1"
```

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
        printf "%s %d\n" "$line" "$(printf "%s" "$line" | wc -c)"
done < "$1"
```

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
        printf "%s %d\n" "$line" "$(wc -c <<< "$line")"
done < "$1"
```

The `wc -c <<< "$line"` variant
will give numbers one higher than the others,
because it includes a newline.

Comment: `wc -c` counts the number of bytes, not characters. For the number of characters, it's `wc -m`.

Comment: `expr "$line" : '.*'` won't work for lines that contain `!` or `substr` or `+` the list of which depends on the `expr` implementation. Also beware of lines that contain bytes not forming valid characters.

Answer (score 2):

This prints each line in a file followed by the length of the line (in terms of number of characters not including the line delimiter in POSIX compliant awk implementations, though some will give you the number of bytes instead).

```
<FOO awk '{print $0,length}'
```

not sure if that is what you are asking though.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for.  The following script should give exactly the output you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1
cat $1 | wc -m
```

Comment: I should have explained, but the problem here is that i need loop to run this code for me over and over because we don't know how many lines are gonna be in our file so i need to set a condition that tells the program to go on running this code until the point that it reaches the condition